# WPF Material Design: Create language selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a language selection in WPF.

I tried to use ComboBox but it didn't look as I wanted and it also seems that the ComboBox doesn't accept images very well in certain sizes.

I have the following code:

```
<ComboBox Height="auto" Foreground="White">
    <materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
        <Image Source="image/eua.png" Width="50"/>
    </materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Image Source="image/italy.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Image Source="image/eua.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

in the code above the image appears as follows

[image]

How can I best do that?

The image below shows the shape you would like it to look.

When selected, show the language flag

[image]

and When clicking on the flag, show the other options

[image]

Comment: You didn't describe what is the problem. What is wrong? What is expected? Please edit question and update.

Comment: it was explained up there that combox is not accepting an image of the size I want, the image is cropped depending on the size

Comment: You should not be using flags to represent languages: http://www.flagsarenotlanguages.com/blog/why-flags-do-not-represent-language/ - as a Brit myself, I get quite offended when the US Flag is used to represent English :) - Also, **what language is "Canadian"**?

Comment: @Dai It the flags were just for example

Comment: @robertsobrel: How are the images the cropped? Your example doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mm8 I added an example to show how it looks using current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try data template

```
<ComboBox>
    <!--Material:Design.Hint-->
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--TextHere-->
                <!--Imagehere-->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: using this code I was unable to show text or image, is there any different way of working?

Comment: does is shows a emptylist of  collection or just none at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. It has been tested with pictures of different sizes. If you have a problem, you can leave a comment.

```
<ComboBox Width="100" Height="35">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" >
            <WrapPanel>
                <Button Width="30" Height="30" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Height="25" Source="image/usa.png" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="English-1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem >
            <WrapPanel>
                <Button Width="30" Height="30" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Height="25" Source="image/england.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="English-2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: I tested it here and it works very well, I can use image or image with text. Thanks me this was of great help, I am still learning to work with wpf